# Certificate Issue - Service Fabric stuck on "Waiting for Nodes"

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am deploying a Service Fabric Cluster using an ARM template.

When using a self-signed certificate everything is good and well. The cluster is created and all nodes are healthy.

But when I do the same with our chained certificate, the cluster gets stuck in "Waiting for nodes".

When I check the validity of the certificate on any of the nodes, I can confirm that the complete chain is trusted.

[Certificate Chain - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS52v.png)

When looking in the windows event log I see the following entries.

**Warning** - "Request failed: PUT https://westeurope.servicefabric.azure.com/runtime/clusters//nodes/ (CorrelationId=,  UtcTime=06/02/2021 07:18:01, Certificate=)
{"nodeTypeRef":"xxxx","ipAddress":"","faultDomain":"4","upgradeDomain":"4","zone":"","location":"","infrastructurePlacementID":"","faultDomainOverride":"","upgradeDomainOverride":"","coordinationGroupID":""}"

**Warning** - "System.Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, List`1 clientCertificates)

at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, List`1 clientCertificates)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.WrpTopologyService.UpdateNodeInfo(String machineName, NodeDescription nodeDescription)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.UpdateNodeTopology(String nodeName)"

**Warning** - "ERROR: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.AgentException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, List`1 clientCertificates)

at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.UpdateNodeTopology(String nodeName)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.d__100.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.NodeBootstrapAgent.d__95.MoveNext()"

**Warning** - "Request failed: POST https://westeurope.servicefabric.azure.com/runtime/clusters/GUID/nodes/NodeInstance/vmextensionRepair (CorrelationId=,  UtcTime=06/02/2021 07:18:01, Certificate=)
{"sequenceNumber":"0","output":""}"

**Error** - "Failed to process adhoc repair response: System.Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, List`1 clientCertificates)

at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RestClient.Invoke(Uri requestUri, String method, String requestBody, List`1 clientCertificates)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.WrpTopologyService.GetAdHocRepairPollResponse(String machineName, VmExtensionAdHocRepairPollRequest request)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.Extension.Core.RepairStrategy.AdHocRepairHandler.PollSFRPForRepair()"

**UPDATE:**
After my original post, I tried to create a cluster via the Azure Portal, using the intended production certificate. I manually created a key vault first and uploaded the certificate as a .pfx. I followed the wizard and low and behold, it worked. Only difference is that it now references the certificate via thumbprint instead of common name (as there was no option in the Azure Portal to tell it otherwise).

[Reference by thumbprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrbG8.png)

Thus, when we deploy via the ARM template using the intended production certificate, it **does not** work, but same ARM template with self-signed certificate **does work**. Doing it manually via the Azure Portal using the intended production certificate, **works** as well. This is really confusing!

Comment: In addition (I'm working on the issue with @Stephan) When creating a cluster from the Azure portal using the same certificate the nodes **do** show up successfully (@Stephan please comment with any information you have on that). Is there any way to get more information on what is causing the 401 error?

Thanks!

Comment: This issue has been resolved. Please see https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/1211#issuecomment-854479790 for solution.